# Android webview load webPage error messaging/unsupported-browser

Tags: android, webview

I develop an android application that has to open url in a webView.
the page open without any issues on the browser, but in my webView it opens a blank page and logs the following error in the logcat.

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).", source: https://myWebsite/static/js/2.4d0092a9.chunk.js (2)
```

And here it is my code

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void setUpWebViewSettings() {
        WebSettings websettings = regularWebView.getSettings();

        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);  

        websettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);    
        websettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);    
        websettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        websettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        websettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    }

private void setUpMuWebView() {
    regularWebView.clearCache(true);
    regularWebView.clearHistory();

    setUpWebViewSettings();

    regularWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });

    regularWebView.loadUrl(<UrlToLoad>);
}
```

What should I do to load the page? and is there any suggested webView library that can help me to open the page inside my application?

Comment: unfortunately you cannot open it in webView, but the CustomTabsIntent can open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not related to the blank page issue, your webView is unable to render the page because of cashing issue.

I had experienced with the same issue when I worked with a react.js team, and clean the cash and made a hard reload on my PC browser to be able to open the webPage on my app webView.
and here it is the steps to do it:

1. Open the URL on the browser on your PC.
2. press F12 to open the Firebug.
3. Long press on the refresh page.
4. select **empty cash and hard reload**

After that try to open the URL from your App WebView.
these steps fixed the issue for me, and it should fix the issue for you if it's a cashing issue, otherwise, you have to you **customtabsintent** or contact the page admin to investigate and fix the issue if you can contact him.

And the **unsupported-browser** error message appease because of using Firebase cloud messaging feature. The Firebase Cloud Messages API in the JavaScript SDK uses APIs which are only supported by a subset of modern browsers, and webView component is using chromium which is not supporting the Firebase cloud messaging. Check out this [related thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/ruFB6VXwle8/lhdp2LVTCQAJ) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, it's worked for me, as you said, it was cashing issue.